# Split an array into m subarrays such that the largest subarray sum is minimized

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, python-3.x, programming-challenge

This is a [Leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/split-array-largest-sum/) -

> *Given an array which consists of non-negative integers and an integer
>   `m`, you can split the array into `m` non-empty continuous subarrays.
>   Write an algorithm to minimize the largest sum among these `m`
>   subarrays.*
>
> ***Note -***
>
> *If `n` is the length of the array, assume the following constraints
>   are satisfied:*
>
> - *1 ≤ `n` ≤ 1000*
> - *1 ≤ `m` ≤ min(50, `n`)*

Here is my solution to this challenge -

> ```
> class Solution(object):
>
>     def __init__(self, nums, m):
>         self.nums = nums
>         self.m = m
>     def split_array(self, nums, m):
>         """
>         :type nums: List[int]
>         :type m: int
>         :rtype: int
>         """
>         min_res = max(nums)
>         max_res = sum(nums)
>         low, high = min_res, max_res
>         while low + 1 < high:
>             mid = low + (high - low)//2
>             if self.is_valid(nums, m, mid):
>                 high = mid
>             else:
>                 low = mid
>         if self.is_valid(nums, m, low):
>             return low
>         return high
>
>     def is_valid(self, nums, m, n):
>         count, current = 1, 0
>         for i in range(len(nums)):
>             if nums[i] > n:
>                 return False
>             current += nums[i]
>             if current > n:
>                 current = nums[i]
>                 count += 1
>         if count > m:
>             return False
>         return True
> ```

Here, I just optimize the binary search method (technique used to search an element in a sorted list), change the condition of `low <= high` to `low + 1 < high` and `mid = low + (high - low) / 2` in case `low + high` is larger than the `max int`.

Here is an example input/output -

```
output = Solution([7,2,5,10,8], 2)
print(output.split_array([7,2,5,10,8], 2))
>>> 18
```

**Explanation -**

There are four ways to split `nums` into two subarrays.
The best way is to split it into `[7,2,5]` and`[10,8]`,
where the largest sum among the two subarrays is only `18`.

Here is the time for this output -

```
%timeit output.split_array([7,2,5,10,8], 2)
12.7 µs ± 512 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

So, I would like to know whether I could make this program shorter and more efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## (Sort of) Unnecessary OOP

A lot of things like LeetCode will require that the solution is in a `class` for likely submission reasons, but if we concern ourselves with *only* the task at hand, I would recommend you get rid of the class and just use functions for this. (And if get rid of the unnecessary class, you'll shorten the code, although, I wouldn't encourage you to be preoccupied with shortening your code.)

Also, if you had to keep the class (for whatever reason), observe:

```
def __init__(self, nums, m):
    self.nums = nums
    self.m = m
```

When you pass parameters like this, you can reuse them over and over again. They are sort of like pseudo-global variables. So you would need to do:

```
def is_valid(self, nums, m, n):
```

it would just be:

```
def is_valid(self):
```

and (in general) you would access `self.m` and `self.n`.

## Iterate over the iterables, not over the `len` of the iterable.

Unless you are mutating `nums` (which I don't believe you are) the more idiomatic way of doing this is iterating through the iterable so:

```
for i in range(len(nums)):
```

becomes:

```
for num in nums:
```

and instances of `nums[i]` are replaced by `num`, for example `if nums[i] > n:` becomes `if num > n:`.

Side note: if you were to need the value `i` and `nums[i]`, you might want to consider utilizing [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) if you need both.

Answer (score 3):

```
if nums[i] > n:
    return False
```

This is unnecesary, you are starting the binary search with max(nums) as minimum, so n will always be at leat equal to max nums[i].

Why is both your constructor and split_array method taking in the parameters of the problem? Either only take them on constructor or make split_array a static method without using constructor.

Why you have min_res and max_res? Either use those in the binary search or just replace them with low and high, no reason to have both those and low/high variables.

If you keep an array of accumulated sums of the array you can change is_valid to do binary search to find the index of the next group. This would change complexity from O(|n| * log(sum(n))) to O(m * log(|n|) * log(sum(n))). For such small amount of n, this is probably not worth doing in this case but its definitly better if you have small m and big n. Instead of reimplementing binary search for this, you could actually use [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html)